# Deleted users appearing in /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux

I am currently performing an IT audit over a Linux server. Is it possible that deleted users/users that do not have access to the server appear in the /etc/sudoers file?

As an additional step, we have confirmed that although alternative authentication methods are configured, example: Windows LDAP, these users do not even appear in the Active Directory as they have been terminated 10 years ago.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. `/etc/sudoers` isn’t tied to specific authentication mechanisms, and there is no common automated way of cleaning it up when users are removed elsewhere.

So unless you have a specific policy in place to remove users from `/etc/sudoers` everywhere when they are removed from your authentication “source of truth”, there’s no reason to expect them to be.

Comment: Can they still appear even if their alias no longer appears in the server itself? When I look at the list of local users in the server, their IDs are not there? Would the /etc/sudoers require a clean up of its own? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, they can. Like I said in the answer, there’s no automated cleanup for `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thank you so much that clears it up, have a good day :)